# PyMySQL: Receiving the error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" when my list inputs exceed one item

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I have two lists, input_algorithm and input_company,each with a varying number of elements, depending on user input. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT fr.company, Usage1.start_time, Usage1.error_message FROM Algorithms, Usage1 
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT Fingerprint.id, Customer.company FROM Fingerprint 
     LEFT JOIN Customer ON Fingerprint.customer_id=Customer.id) fr ON fr.id=Usage1.licensing_fingerprint_id 
     WHERE fr.company IN (%s) AND Algorithms.id=Usage1.algorithm_id 
     AND Algorithms.algorithm IN (%s)", (input_company, input_algorithm))
```

If I run this when both lists only have one element it does the job. But when either of the lists have more than one element it says `pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)').`

I've also tried using executemany instead of just execute but it still doesn't work. In that case it says TypeError: not enough arguments for format string when a list has more than one element and if both have just one element it says 'not enough arguments for format string'. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: run `cursor.mogrify` on your input to see what it returns, the formatted query is not correct per the traceback

Comment: SELECT fr.company, Usage1.start_time, Usage1.error_message FROM Algorithms, Usage1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT Fingerprint.id, Customer.company FROM Fingerprint LEFT JOIN Customer ON Fingerprint.customer_id=Customer.id) fr ON fr.id=Usage1.licensing_fingerprint_id WHERE fr.company IN (('Company1','Company2')) AND Algorithms.id=Usage1.algorithm_id AND Algorithms.algorithm IN (('algorithm1','algorithm2'))

Comment: That doesn’t look correct to me when mogrified

Comment: I edited it a minute back, can you take a look at it again please? And do u have any suggestions on how i can fix it?

Comment: I think it’s treating them as column names not variable names not sure since I don’t work with MySQL

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the extra parentheses (See your mogrified query). These causes the error, as you can also see in [this SQLize Demo](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=9da54e45a9352a1b1f9a7a44d82de07d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80). So replace `IN (%s)` with `IN %s`.

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT fr.company, Usage1.start_time, Usage1.error_message FROM Algorithms, Usage1 
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT Fingerprint.id, Customer.company FROM Fingerprint 
     LEFT JOIN Customer ON Fingerprint.customer_id=Customer.id) fr ON fr.id=Usage1.licensing_fingerprint_id 
     WHERE fr.company IN %s AND Algorithms.id=Usage1.algorithm_id 
     AND Algorithms.algorithm IN %s", (input_company, input_algorithm))
```